# Branch git flow, start, which branch?

Tags: devops, branch, local, git-flow

So i created a git flow with the command "git flow init".

I'm on develop.

If i do "git flow start feature MY_FEATURE", it's duplicate develop for a feature.

"git flow start feature MY_FEATURE-2" duplicate develop or the branch current?

Thanks you.

Comment: It's "git flow feature start MY_FEATURE", and i had tested in local. Always develop the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"feature start" will always automatically create a feature-branch from the develop-branch called feature/.
"feature finish" will merge the feature-branch back into the develop-branch and delete the feature-branch afterwards.

That's the way this convention works

Have a look at this graphic for better understanding

[How feature-branches in gitflow work](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#feature-branches)